# Getting warning 404 for images jasmine-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I get this annoying 404 warnings for every image in my app. I tried different solutions provided on stackoverflow but still no success. My unit tests are passing but there are this 404 warnings.

**karma config**

```
var baseDir = 'client';

module.exports = {

  //This is the list of file patterns to load into the browser during testing.
  files: [
    ......
    baseDir + '/src/app/app.js',
    baseDir + '/test/unit/**/*.spec.js',
    {
      pattern: baseDir + '/assets/**/*.json',
      watched: true,
      served: true,
      included: false
    },
    {
      pattern: baseDir + '/assets/images/**/*.png',
      watched: false,
      included: false,
      served: true
    }
  ],

  proxies :  {
  '/images/': '/base/images/'
  },
};
```

**Warning**

[image: Screenshot of Warning]

**Structure**
[image: Screenshot of the structure of the App]

**UPDATE**

I removed this __test from url so now I get:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /assets/images/map_WRO_lrg.png ..
```

I added this proxies by karma official suggestion http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html:

```
  proxies: {
    "/img/": "/base/test/images/"
  },
```

and also tried with this:

```
proxies: {
  "/img/": "http://localhost:9876/base/test/images/"
},
```

but again same warnings...

Comment: That's because it's looking for the images in `/__test/assets/images/` where as your images are present in `client/assets/images/`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera so what are you suggesting as best solution for this?

Comment: What I mean is can I add some patter in karma.config like this pattern: /__test/assets/images/**/*.png'? I suppose not.

Answer (score 4):

You should try adding the proxy without like this:

`proxies: {
    "/assets/": "/assets/"
  }`